# react mui datagrid : dynamic column

Tags: reactjs, mui-datatable

How can I hide/show a column in react, using mui, after a fetch event.

Using fetch for example :

```
const getData=()=>{
   fetch(url +'/rha/apicall/getData/'
    ,{
      headers : { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
        }
    )
      .then(function(response){

        enqueueSnackbar('Data Loaded',{variant:'info'});

        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(myJson) {
        console.log(myJson);
        console.log(columns);
        columns[1].hide=false;
        rows = myJson.adh;
        setData(myJson)
      });
  }
```

Rows is updating well, but column is not working.

Comment: please. provide your component with Column, so community will know how to help, no guess

Comment: It's irrelevant. A column name has no impact on the question. Btw, the columns is very large.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one give a single answer, here is one :

conditionnal loading.

```
    const [isLoaded, setLoaded] = React.useState(false);
..

...

 .then(function(myJson) {
        console.log(myJson);
        console.log(columns);
        columns[1].hide=false;
        rows = myJson.adh;
        setLoaded(true);
        setData(myJson)
      });

then in the render :
 {isLoaded? 
        <DataGrid.../>
:
<p>Loading</p>
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks you bot. But hey, everything has been said here. "use conditionnal loading", then an example of code. Can't do more, since I answer it myself.

Answer (score 0):

You now have a `columnVisibilityModel` that allows you to control the visibility. It will probably simplify your problem

https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-visibility/#controlled-visible-columns